# CLOSED: pug - make text italic within h1 tag

Tags: html, pug

I am using the `pugjs` template engine on my `expressjs` server, but between the pugjs docs and my own experimentation, I cannot figure out how to make text italicized within an h1 tag.

In regular HTML, what I want looks like this: `<h1>This is text: <i>This is Italic Text</i></h1>`. But when I try the equivalent of that in pugjs: `h1 This is Text i This is Italic Text`, it doesn't work, outputting

> This is Text i This is Italic Text

instead of what I want. If I drop the `i` part to the next line, the text comes out on separate lines, not what i want.

If anyone knows how to do this, please let me know. I am sure I am missing something very basic. Thanks in advance, Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading a previously deleted answer on this question, I got an idea:

```
h1
  |This is Text
  i  This is Italic Text
```

This renders out to:

```
<h1>This is Text<i> This is Italic Text</i></h1>
```

which is perfect for what I need.

I'm sorry that I lost the alias of the user who posted the previous answer, but *thank you*.